# Windows Server guest changes and ramifications after being migrated to SSD?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2016, storage-area-network, ssd

This particular environment, it's VMWare guests that have been moved to all-flash SAN, but that shouldn't be particularly relevant.

I'm quite familiar with `>winsat formal` from SO questions like [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/1006877/windows-10-optimize-drives-shows-ssd-as-hard-disk-drive) to get Windows to re-test the OS disk. However:

1. Windows (Server, 2016) only recognizes the change on the OS
   drive.`>winsat disk -drive d` (as example) runs the tests, but
   Defrag/Optimize util still sees all non-OS drives as HDD, and will
   happily defrag them.
2. I haven't yet been able to get even `winsat diskformal` to properly run
   and "take" over Remote Powershell Sessions. (It appears to run fine via invoke-command, but Defrag will still see it as HDD, unlike running it via RDP session.)

In the meantime, I've disabled the auto-defrag task on all the servers (probably should have been off already.)

So my questions are:

1. Does anyone know of a method other than winsat to make Windows
   re-evaluate it's attached drives? (Or a way to make winsat
   accept/care about the values of non-OS drives.
2. Has anyone gotten even "winsat formal" to run correctly via
   invoke-command?
3. Other than wasting electrons and write-cycles, does Server 2016
   do anything differently with disks detected as SSD vs HDD besides
   allowing defrag, when TRIM is not available. (Being a SAN, it's
   not.)

Comment: You should be having a chat with your storage admin, and possibly the VMware admin, about this. The SAN could present the volume as thin proivisioned, which Windows would [recognize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E41Kc.png), and then you could re-enable Optimize (as it would just unmap, similarly to local SSD storage).

Comment: Interesting @MichaelHampton. I know the actual .VMDKs are thin-provisioned on the backend. (NetApp.) I'm not super-familiar virtual disk thin-provisioning being something the guest os can be aware of. I'll do some research and ask the vm/san folks.

Comment: Ahh, looks like that's using the UNMAP command, which is a (i)SCSI command/primitive. Right, minor detail, these are served over NFS, not iSCSI. (No, I don't know why...)

Comment: Apparently [you need NFS 4.2](https://serverfault.com/q/731632/126632) for this to work.